# Memory Management with returning char* function

Tags: c++, windows, linux, compiler-construction, memory-management

Today, without much thought, I wrote a simple function return to a char* based on a switch statement of given enum values. This, however, made me wonder how I could release that memory. What I did was something like this:

```
char* func()
{
    char* retval = new char[20];
    // Switch blah blah - will always return some value other than NULL since default:
    return retval;
}
```

I apologize if this is a naive question, but what is the best way to release the memory seeing as I cannot delete the memory after the return and, obviously, if I delete it before, I won't have a returned value. What I was thinking as a viable solution was something like this

```
void func(char*& in)
{
    // blah blah switch make it do something
}

int main()
{
    char* val = new char[20];

    func(val);
    // Do whatever with func (normally func within a data structure with specific enum set so could run multiple times to change output)

    delete [] val;
    val = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Would anyone have anymore insight on this and/or explanation on which to use?

Regards,
Dennis M.

Comment: Your second code example doesn't make any sense. You return in a void function assign a character value to a pointer, have a reference to a pointer (valid but not often usefull).

Comment: Sorry, typo. There should be no return.

Comment: By the way, if you're returning a `char *` I suppose you need to return a string instead of a single character, and in that case you should use `new char[size]`/`delete []`.

Comment: Yes, I apologize for the typos in the second example. I wrote it on the fly at the time of this post just very briefly without checking it over.

Comment: @Raged : there is still problem. It's not typo. It's that you don't know `val = NULL;` before `delete val;` doesn't make sense!

Comment: @Nawaz: Sorry, again this edit was made in haste (had a busy day today, was in and out). You can see before that, in my original edit, I simply just added the line afterward. I have revised the OP and there should be no errors in the second example. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write such functions in pair, like

```
Xyz* CreateXyz();
void DestroyXyz(Xyz *xyz);


Abc* NewAbc();
void DeleteAbc(Abc *abc);
```

Or you simply can transfer the responsibilty of deleting Xyz/Abc to the clients, i.e ones who call the function must also do `delete` on the returned object after using it.

Whatever you choose, make it clear in your documentation *how* the created object should be destroyed.

I would prefer pair-functions, especially if there is lot of things to consider before deleting!

By the way, you should prefer using `std::string`, instead of `char*`. Make use of STL as much as you can. They can solve most of your problems! The above advice is for situations where STL doesn't fit! In general, prefer STL!

Comment: Thanks! I do often use STL, however, I was just wondering in this case how to make this work. Awesome solution.

Comment: I would add that creating a class to hold the resource (and release it in the destructor) is often better. So create XYZ and ABC classes rather then New/Delete functions for them.

Comment: @Winston Ewert: that is also good. but if one creates use-and-throw kind of objects and that too frequently, then it's better to have pair-functions (as described in my post) in your design, so that users can destroy an object immediately, after using it.

Comment: @Nawaz, I'm not sure what you mean use-and-throw. I'm assuming you mean that you create the object, use it for a short period of time, and then get rid of it. (I'd suggest throw isn't a good choice of terminology for that because throwing is used for exceptions.) However, in that case I want to create an object on my stack so that its automatically destroyed when the function ends. I'm not seeing how using the paired functions would be better there.

Comment: @Winston Ewert: IF he wants to return the object from a function, in that case pair-functions make sense. This is another scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555961/how-to-use-a-class-in-dll/4556092#4556092

Comment: @Nawaz, there are three types of functions which are consideration here: Normal functions, creation functions, and deletion functions. Creation and deletion functions are paired the same code should call both of them. If a normal function creates an object, it should destroy it. However, if a normal function returns an object, it breaks the rules because now some other code must destroy the object. Any pair of creation/deletion functions can be converted into the constructor/destructor of a class.

Comment: Of course, sometimes you must return an object from your function. The creation/deletion pairing does not seem to help there. My own preference is to use some sort of reference counting smart pointer to make sure the object is destroyed when its no longer in use. Regarding the dll example, thats a valid example. However, I'd probably want to hide that detail of implementation. I'd probably use a static method to construct the object and use a smart pointer to ensure that my own deletion code gets run.

Comment: @Winston Ewert : did you read when I said "IF **he** wants to return the object from a function, in that case pair-functions make sense."??

Comment: @Winston Ewert : Also did you see that link?

Comment: @Nawaz, I'm just not seeing the connection that you are between wanting to the return the object and the helpfulness of a pair function. Is the function you are talking about the Create*() function or some other function?

Comment: @Nawaz, ok, I think I see what you are saying now. If you must return an object from a function like that, yes, pairing is a good idea. My point was that its a rarely a good idea to return an object like that. (Your dll example being an exception)

Comment: @Winston : What you're discussing is design, you probably would not design the way topic starter have designed his code, but that is a different question altogether. I was merely suggesting him what to do next if he wants to return an object from a function, how to destroy it, etc. Anyway, as for his example, I would probably use `std:string`. No Create(),no Destroy(). :-)

Comment: @Winston : Since I would probably use `std::string`, so I kind of agree with what you said. It's just that I was focusing on his problem of freeing the memory than his design. Please note the name of this topic also. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz, but isn't having Create/Delete paired functions design also? I interpreted the question as being one of how to write code which avoid leaking stuff. The correct answer, as I think you'll agree, it almost always to encapsulate it an object.

Comment: @Winston: Yes, that is design also, but it's his design, not mine. He wrote a func() function (which is actually Create() function, so I just renamed it), and I suggested him if he is going to do that, then he better write another func2() called Destroy().

Comment: @Winston : Correct answer could be many, as long as it serves it's purpose and doesn't leak memory.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using an STL type or other class instead of returning a raw pointer? For instance, if your `char *` is a string, use `std::string` instead and avoid any risk of leaks:

```
std::string func()
{
    std::string retval("");

    // Switch blah blah - will always return some value other than NULL since default:

    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to return raw pointers from a function, you must make really clear on the documentation whose is the responsibility of deleting the pointer, i.e. who *owns* it. In this case, you should state explicitly that the pointer ownership is transferred to the caller, who is responsible to `delete` it.

Although many people are OK with just specifying the ownership in the documentation, often it's better to enforce this policy in the code. In particular, *smart pointers* are often used for this: the current C++ standard provides the `std::auto_ptr`, a smart pointer which transfers ownership on copy, i.e. when you return it to the caller, you're transferring the ownership to the target `std::auto_ptr`. Notice that `std::auto_ptr` automagically `delete`s the pointed memory on its destruction if it still owns it. The upcoming C++ standard provides `std::unique_ptr` that works in a similar fashion, but using move semantic.

Unfortunately, `std::auto_ptr` isn't thought for arrays (which need `delete []` instead of `delete`), so you cannot use for your your purpose. I think that the decision of not including an `auto_ptr` for arrays was made deliberately, because the STL already provides all the containers you may need if you need to return a collection of items which handle by their own memory management and copy.

In particular, for strings you should simply use `std::string` and forget completely about this kind of memory management and pointer ownership problems.

Answer (score 0):

In this case whoever calls the func() should release the memory when its not needed. But the correct deletion happens like this:

```
delete val;
val = NULL;
```