# How to wrap a C++ class in a C based dll or a CLI based dll?

Tags: c++, c, dll, c++-cli

I am told to import my writen class in C++ into a dll and then use that dll in a c# application. Following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555961/how-to-use-a-class-in-dll) I created the dll, but I can't simply use it in a C# application since there are some issues concerning it:

1. What should I place for the return type of my factory function?
2. What is the equivalent of `const wchar_t*` which is my constructors argument type?
3. How can I retrieve and use my functions return type which is of type `vector< wstring>`?

These are the problems that prevent me from using my C++ DLL inside my C# applications. I was told that I need to create a wrapper with C++/CLI and then use that inside my C#. But sadly I have no idea about it, I don't know C++.net.

The only thing that currently seems to be a bit more sensational to me is to make it somehow compatible with C and then create a C DLL and use that in my C# application. I have read that in C, class object pointers are accessible through `HANDLE`s, so I thought that would be good idea to get things going without a lot of changes.

So the question is how can I use Handles to access my class objects in C and use them? And how can I convert a `vector<wstring>` to its C counterpart? 
If I want to use CLI to create a wrapper (DLL?) for my C++ DLL, to be used in other dotnet apps what should I do?

Comment: The windows `HANDLE` type are just `void *`s

Comment: `const wchar_t *` is an extremely vague parameter specification. Perhaps it is a UTF-16LE encoded Unicode string with a NUL terminator that is being passed into the constructor.  If so, it is close to .NET's `System::String`, which is a code-unit counted UTF-16LE encoded Unicode string. (At least it has `const` so we know that it's immutable and therefore not an in-out parameter.)

Comment: .NET `char` marshals to `wchar_t`.

Comment: It is also unclear if the data pointed to by the `const wchar_t *` parameter must be maintained for the life of the object or only for the duration of the constructor call.

Comment: @Joel `char` is a _C#_ alias for _.NET's_ `Char`. There is no marshalling involved. `Char` is a `u16char_t`, which is weakly represented as a `wchar_t`. (`wchar_t` is a portable type with no specified size or encoding/character set but in VC++, it is 2 bytes and usually holds a UTF-16LE code unit—that is, a whole or half of a Unicode codepoint.)

Comment: OK, but unless you go out of your way to have some other type of encoding or are getting string data from an external source, `System.Char` goes to `wchar_t` in C++/CLI. It interoperates pretty simply with native strings in the Windows API (otherwise P/Invoke would be much more difficult).

Comment: Notably, it is listed as such at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wf2yk2k.aspx (edited with the link I was really looking for).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make a `C wrapper` for a `C++` class to be used in for example a `C#` application you can do the following.

In Visual Studio choose `Win32 Console Application` and Enter a name, Then click next and on the next pane choose `DLL` and click finish. When you are done you are represented with a DLL project including 3 files.

```
testdll.h 
testdll.cpp
dllmain
```

Delete everything that exists inside your `testdll.h` and `testdll.cpp` files and copy the following contents to each respectively. Add these lines to your testdll.h

```
// Our C wrapper for creating a dll to be used in C# apps

// The following ifdef block is the standard way of creating macros which make exporting 
// from a DLL simpler. All files within this DLL are compiled with the TESTDLL_EXPORTS
// symbol defined on the command line. This symbol should not be defined on any project
// that uses this DLL. This way any other project whose source files include this file see 
// TESTDLL_API functions as being imported from a DLL, whereas this DLL sees symbols
// defined with this macro as being exported.
#ifdef  TESTDLL_EXPORTS
#define  TESTDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define  TESTDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C"
{
     TESTDLL_API int OurTestFunction(int x, int y);                         
}
```

It is inside this extern "C" block where you define your interface, functions to access your class member functions.Note the `TESTDLL` before the function prototype. All of your functions must be proceeded by that.

Add these to your testdll.cpp file:

```
#include "testdll.h"
#include "ourClass.h"

#define DLL_EXPORT

extern "C"
{
    OurClass ourObject;
    TESTDLL_API int OurTestFunction(int x, int y)
    {
        return ourObject.Add(x,y);
    }
}
```

You compile this and get a C based dll which can be used in a C# application.
There are couple of things to notice though, The more important ones are:

1. You need to understand that the code you use as a proxy- i mean
   function definition inside your `testdll.h`, must only use C
   compatible types, it is C after all not C++.
2. is that you would want to be able to allocate new objects of your
   class instead of just using one global object to access all methods.

For this, if you need to pass your class objects between member functions, you need to first convert it to a `void*` which C can understand and then pass it and use it to access your member functions of whatever.

For example I would have something like this inside my `testdll.h` in order to make user capable of managing the objects indirectly:

```
#ifdef TESTDLL_EXPORTS
#define TESTDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TESTDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C"
{
    TESTDLL_API int OurTestFunction(int x, int y);                      

    TESTDLL_API void*  CreateHandle();
    TESTDLL_API void*  GetCurrentHandle();
    TESTDLL_API void   DisposeCurrentHandle();
    TESTDLL_API void   SetCurrentHandle(void* handle);
    TESTDLL_API void*  GetHandle();
    TESTDLL_API void   DisposeHandle(void*);
    TESTDLL_API void   DisposeArrayBuffers(void);
}
```

And inside my testdll.cpp I would define them as :

```
#include "testdll.h"
#include "ourClass.h"

#define DLL_EXPORT

extern "C"
{
    OurClass *ourObject;

    TESTDLL_API int OurTestFunction(int x, int y)
    {
        //return ourObject.Add(x,y); -- not any more !!
        ourObject = reinterpret_cast<OurClass *>(GetHandle());
    }

    //Handle operations
    TESTDLL_API void* CreateHandle()
    {
        if (ourObject == nullptr)
        {
            ourObject = new OurClass ;
        }
        else
        {
            delete ourObject ;
            ourObject = new OurClass ;
        }
        return reinterpret_cast<void*>(ourObject);
    }

    TESTDLL_API void* GetCurrentHandle()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<void*>(ourObject );
    }

    TESTDLL_API void  DisposeCurrentHandle()
    {
        delete ourObject ;
        ourObject = nullptr;
    }

    TESTDLL_API void  SetCurrentHandle(void* handle)
    {
        if (handle != nullptr)
        {
            ourObject = reinterpret_cast<OurClass *>(handle);
        }
        else
        {
            ourObject = new OurClass ;
        }

    }

    //factory utility function
    TESTDLL_API void* GetHandle()
    {
        void* handle = GetCurrentHandle();
        if (handle != nullptr)
        {
            return handle;
        }
        else
        {
            ourObject = new OurClass ;
            handle = reinterpret_cast <void*>(ourObject );
        }
        return handle;
    }

    CDLL_API void  DisposeHandle(void* handle)
    {
        OurClass * tmp = reinterpret_cast<OurClass *>(handle);
        delete tmp;
    }

    TESTDLL_API void DisposeArrayBuffers(void)
    {
        ourObject = reinterpret_cast<OurClass *>(GetHandle());
        return ourObject ->DisposeBuffers();//This is a member function defined solely for this purpose of being used inside this wrapper to delete any allocated resources by our class object.
    }
}
```

And when we compile this `Dll`, we can easily work with it inside our C# application. Before being able to use our functions defined in this dll we need to use appropriate `[ImportDll()]`. So for our TestDll we would write:

```
[DllImport(@"TestDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int OurTestFunction(int firstNumber,int secondNumber);
```

And finally use it like:

```
private void btnReadBigram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = OurTestFunction(10,50);
    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
}
```

This is all I did to make my C++ class member functions accessible inside a C# application without any hassle.

**Note**:
When compiling your C# application make sure you have chosen the `x86` Platform for compiling your project not `AnyCpu`.You can change your platform through properties.

**Note 2**:
For knowing how to create a C++/CLI wrapper for your native C++ class read this: [C++/CLI wrapper for your native C++ class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17913455/938244).

Answer (score 2):

Using a native C++ class directly from C# is technically possible, but it's not trivial, and it's rarely even a good idea. For starters, you have to know the names to use to import from the DLL, which will be the names after C++ name-mangling. You also can't directly access things like `vector` from C#.

There are basically two good options:

The first is to write a DLL with a C interface that uses only types that can be marshalled into CLR types. You may use pointers along with the `IntPtr` type, but you can't really dereference those pointers. You can pretty much just store them in your C# code and then pass them back to the native DLL when needed. And you can also use simple `struct` types as long as you don't need deep copy to work on them. This option involves using P/Invoke.

The second option is to write a mixed-mode C++/CLI assembly that implements all the logic that needs to access your native code. This assembly can directly access classes and data from your C# code and also directly access your native code, although you should be forewarned that there are annoying breaks where you can't mix the two. For example, a `ref class` in C++/CLI can't have a `shared_ptr` member. However, it can have a raw C++ pointer as a member. A (mixed-mode) native class can also have access to a CLR handle type and make calls into the C# code through this. This option involves using C++ Interop.

It's worth noting that you could also go the other way with C++ Interop. You could have your C# code access a mixed-mode C++/CLI assembly that provides a .NET interface to some native code. However, you will still have to do some translation in this case so it's not hugely better than the first option.

A full tutorial on C++ Interop would be rather lengthy. I suggest you read up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x8kf7zx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and do some further investigation of C++ Interop on Google.

Answer (score 1):

C++/CLI introduces managed objects, for which the pointer token * should be replaced with a ^, and a 'new' should be replaced with 'gcnew', you don't need to delete these objects when you're done with them, they'll be garbage collected, [edit] managed classes have a **ref** keyword in their definition [/edit].

Wrapping the C++ **MyClass** class in a C++/CLI wrapper class **WrapperCLass** could look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class MyClass
{
public:
    void ShowStuff(const wchar_t *a)
    {
        wprintf(a);
    }
};

public ref class WrapperClass
{
    MyClass *wrapped;
public:
    WrapperClass()
    {
        wrapped = new MyClass;

    }
    ~WrapperClass()
    {
        delete wrapped;
    }
    void ShowStuff(IntPtr string)
    {
        wrapped->ShowStuff((const wchar_t *)string.ToPointer());
    }
};
```

If you generate a dll with this, you'll be able to use it as a reference in your C# project
and you won't have to use the factory function mechanism.
In C++/CLI are available, so **const wchar_t *** is as wel.

To convert a **System::String** to a **const wchar_t *** you could use something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WrapperClass w = new WrapperClass();
            IntPtr tmp;
            w.ShowStuff(tmp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("Test"));
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

(There could very well be better ways to do this...)

For your return type you'll have to do the conversion in your wrapper class. Make some .net collection, iterate through your vector, convert the wstring to a System::String, and add it to the .net collection, and return that.

Comment: Technically, `ref` is not a keyword; `ref class` is one of the so called whitespaced keywords. The point is that `ref` is not modifier  of `class` because `ref class` and `class` are entirely different things.

Comment: For marshalling strings, I would probably recommend passing them into C++/CLI as `System::String^` and then using an RAII-based marshalling class. Otherwise, you get exception safety issues. Naturally, you could use `finally` here, too, but personally I find RAII much simpler.

Comment: @Pruyque:Thank you very much.But what if i have a dll ready and want to use it in instead of rewriting the native class inside my managed class?

Comment: Instead of making a **new MyClass** directly, you could **LoadLibrary** your dll, and use your factory function to instantiate the wrapped object. You'd still have to write a method in the wrapper for every method you want to call in the wrapped class (I know, not funny...). @Tom: Cool, I didn't know that yet (+1)...